# TS2322 in React UseState fuction: Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyDataType[] | undefined>> should not be undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a React component that calls another component and I'm getting a TypeScript error I can't figure out how to fix.

This is the error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyDataType[] | undefined>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyDataType[]>>'.
```

Simplified code:

**child component**

```
interface MyProps {
  data: MyDataType[],
  queueIndex: number,
  setQueue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<MyDataType[]>>,
}

const QueueForm: React.VFC<MyProps> = (
  {
    data, queueIndex, setQueue,
  }: MyProps,
) => {

   // Do stuff
```

**parent component**

```
const PageQueueForm: React.VFC<MyProps> = ({
  isLoading, setIsLoading, queueIndex, setQueueIndex,
}: MyProps) => {
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState<MyDataType[]>();

  function useGetQueue() {
    return useQuery<MyDataType[], Error>(
      `myUrl${groupUuid}`,
      async () => fetchWithAuth(getQueueByGroup(groupUuid)),
      {
        staleTime: DAY_MILLISECONDS,
        onSuccess: (data) => {
          if (data && data[0]) {
            data.map(addStuff);
            setQueue(data);
        },
      },
    );
  }

  const {
    data, status, error, isFetching,
  } = useGetQueue();

  // Must reset state with cached query data if the component is reloaded.
  if (status === 'success' && !queue) {
    setQueue(data);
  }

  // Make sure we have at least one item to review.
  if (status === 'success' && data && queue) {
    return (
      <IonPage>
        <IonContent>
          <QueueForm
            data={data}
            queueIndex={queueIndex}
            // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS.
            setQueue={setQueue}
          />
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
  }
```

**types.ts**

```
export type MyDataType = AddType & {
  myObject: MyObject,
};

type AddType = {
  score: number,
  id: string,
  links: LinkType,
};

type MyObject = {
  body: ReactFragment,
  id: number,
  uuid: string,
  image: ResponsiveImageCard | undefined,
};
```

I tried checking for the existing of the function like this: `if (setQueue && status === 'success' && data && queue)`.  However, I still get the same error.

So somehow I need to rewrite my code so that the `setQueue` SetStateAction is always `MyDataType[]` and not `undefined`.  How do I do that?

Comment: It would super helpful to provide a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you declare `setQueue`:

```
const [queue, setQueue] = useState<MyDataType[]>();
```

which means its initial value is `undefined`, hence the error. If you start with an empty array it should do the trick:

```
const [queue, setQueue] = useState<MyDataType[]>([]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it was tangentially related code that just needed a `data` assertion.  I'm accepting now, many thanks.

Comment: Lovely, glad I could help!